# MVC view can't see model in separate project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC view in one project (my web project). I'm trying to specify that it should inherit from a class (the model) in another project, but that class isn't visible to my view. The model class's project is in the References of the project in which the view resides. Why can't my view see the model class? Here's the view in its entirety:

```
<%@ Page Title="Title" 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Models.PropertyDetailsModel>"
    MasterPageFile="../MvcMasterPage.Master" %>
```

Models.PropertyDetailsModel is highlighed in red and when I hover over it, it says that it can't resolve the symbol PropertyDetailsModel.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you try to build your Model class/project?

Comment: Yes. I've built a number of times. Still no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all I had to do was change this:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Models.PropertyDetailsModel>"
```

to this:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`1[Models.PropertyDetailsModel]"
```

Wacky!

Answer (score 4):

In your `~/web.config` make sure that in the `<assemblies>` section you have the assembly containing this model:

```
<assemblies>
    ...
    <add assembly="TheAssemblyContainingYourModel" />
</assemblies>
```

Then run the project to see if it works. Don't pay attention to the red squiggles. Visual Studio Intellisense in views is not to be trusted.

P.S: in `~/web.config` there's also a `<namespaces>` section where you could put the namespace that contains your model which will DRY your views:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="TheNamespaceContainingYourModel" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

and then in all your views in the entire application you can directly reference the models without the need to fully qualify them:

```
<%@ Page Title="Title" 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="ViewPage<PropertyDetailsModel>"
    MasterPageFile="../MvcMasterPage.Master" %>
```

Comment: What would I put for Version and PublicKeyToken?

Comment: @birdus, if your assembly is not strongly signed you don't need to put anything. You could just leave the name. If on the other hand you have multiple versions of the same assembly in the GAC and it is strongly signed you will have to specify the fully qualified assembly name. The same way this is done with the BCL assemblies.

Comment: "Could not load file or assembly. File not found."

Ideas?

Comment: @birdus, is the assembly referenced? Is the assembly present in the bin folder? What's the exact name of the assembly? Is it part of the solution containing the ASP.NET MVC application?